# UITableView not populating from UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uitableview, delegates

I have this problem I've been sitting with. My tableView that I put inside my UIView is not populating or sometimes I get an exception.

```
// .h
@interface List : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    UITableView *mTableView;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
//------------------------------
// .m
@synthesize tableView=mTableView;

//Further I do the normal viewDidUnload stuff = nill
//And the numberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfRowsInSection and 

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath:");
    NSLog(@"Table View: %@",[tableView description]);
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Hi";
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

I get as output:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<List 0x6a78000> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableView.'
```

or just a list of empty cells, not even "Hi" as a title.

Comment: That code looks fine. Does the debugger give a line number for the error? Although I'm not sure about printing [tableView description]; you shouldn't have any need for that. (THe method wouldn't be called if it wasn't available)

Comment: At the moment I get the exception, so NO NSLogs run at all :(. The [tableView description] I put in to see if it selects the right tableView for use. I have suspicions here also, but at the moment I get the exception.

Comment: try setting the property to retain instead of readonly.

Comment: The problem isn't with the code you've shown us, We'll need to see more.

Comment: have you set the delegate and datasource of the table in IB?

Comment: why is the table view property readonly ????

Comment: @TotumusMaximus already tried, nothing. @ AmitShah, sorry that code is all I implemented. I am also reading a tutorial (for which I downloaded the code, and seems to work) but mine still doesnt work. Also I'm not gona be near my Mac for a few hours :( Sorry. Will Look at my question later or 2morrow. Very Sorry indeed.

Comment: @glogic: Yes @ Vince, It was readonly in an example I got that seemed to work, retain does nothing.

Comment: @glogic repost that as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost sure that this error occurs because you have improperly connected your `UITableView` . You should delete an ivar mTableView, an `IB` outlet property tableView and `@synthesize` . Then DELETE AN OUTLET IN `IB`. Then, connect it again by dragging it from the interface builder and DO NOT TYPE ANY CODE in your class. Xcode will do all stuff for you (create a property, synthesize it and do MM things)

Comment: I did it your way, still nothing, the cellForRowAtIndexPath seems to run 5 times (I put NSLog inside) but theres still no tablecells. (I'm at work, I cannot upload images)

Comment: nevertheless I'm still sure that the problem is in wrong connection of outlets...try to delete ALL outlets and connect them again. I've had this problem a few days ago...My problem was in missing outlet

Comment: btw, the property MUST NOT BE READ-ONLY it should looks like:
'@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *wallTableView;' with an ivar 'UITableView *wallTableView;' and synthersize '@synthesize wallTableView;' note you don't type this code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have set the delegate and the datasource of the table within Interface Builder

Answer (score 0):

If you do not do anything with your IBOutlet why do you have it? The method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is Called by the nib-File for the tableView instance created in the nib.Your Class as a delegate of this instance receives this call. Being the delegate of the tableView in the nib is all you need.